# Add JUnit test with @Autowired for Spring @Service

Tags: java, spring, web-services, junit, dozer

I've checked all other posts and blogs/wikis about this topic, but there's still something wrong with our project setup.

There's project `ParentProject` and there are multiple subprojects. For this specific problem, we take `API` and `WS` into consideration.

There's an interface `Service` (annotated as `@WebService` and `@SOAPBinding`) declared in the `API`, and its implementation is in `WS` (annotated as `@WebService` and `@Service`).

When trying to implement a JUnit test for this implementation, for some reason `maven clean install` (in Eclipse) ends in **BUILD FAILURE**

Some of the problems encountered:

```
Could not find an 'annotation declaring class' for annotation type [interface org.springframework.test.context.ActiveProfiles] and class [class com.x.ws.services.x.ServiceTest]
java.lang.NullPointerException
...
After test class: context [[TestContext@c0843d testClass = ServiceImplTest, testInstance = [null], testMethod = [null], testException = [null], mergedContextConfiguration = [MergedContextConfiguration@2e0dcb testClass = ServiceImplTest, locations = '{classpath:spring-config-business-test.xml}', classes = '{}', activeProfiles = '{}', contextLoader = 'org.springframework.test.context.support.DelegatingSmartContextLoader']]], dirtiesContext [false].
java.lang.NullPointerException
...
Caught exception while allowing TestExecutionListener 
[org.springframework.test.context.support.DependencyInjectionTestExecutionListener@1bcdc8] to prepare test instance [com.x.ws.services.x.ServiceImplTest@5d285b]
org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'com.x.ws.services.x.ServiceImplTest': Injection of autowired dependencies failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Could not autowire field: private com.x.api.services.x.Service com.x.ws.services.x.ServiceImplTest.service; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No matching bean of type [com.x.api.services.x.Service] found for dependency: expected at least 1 bean which qualifies as autowire candidate for this dependency. Dependency annotations: {@org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired(required=true)}
```

This is the current **ServiceImplTest**:

```
@RunWith(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.class)
@ContextConfiguration(
        locations = {
//                "classpath:spring-config-business.xml",
//                "classpath:spring-config-business-cxf.xml",
//                "classpath:dozer-config.xml"//,
                "classpath:spring-config-business-test.xml"
        })
//        classes = Service.class)
//@ComponentScan("com.<service_package>")
//@TestExecutionListeners({
    //org.springframework.test.context.support.DependencyInjectionTestExecutionListener.class,
    //org.springframework.test.context.support.DirtiesContextTestExecutionListener.class,
    //org.springframework.test.context.transaction.TransactionalTestExecutionListener.class
    })
//@Profile("test")
public class ServiceImplTest {

    @Autowired
    private Service service;
...
}
```

This is the **spring-config-business-test.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xmlns:p="http://www.springframework.org/schema/p" xmlns:tx="http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx" xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
    xsi:schemaLocation="
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx/spring-tx.xsd
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/context http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context.xsd"
>

    <!-- Allow @Autowired Annotation -->
    <context:annotation-config/>

    <context:component-scan base-package="com.x.api"></context:component-scan>    
    <bean id="dataSource"
        class="org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.SingleConnectionDataSource"
        p:driverClassName="${jdbcDriverDB2.className}"
        p:url="${testDataSource.url}"
        p:username="${testDataSource.user}"
        p:password="${testDataSource.password}"
        p:suppressClose="true" />

</beans>
```

It is not working when using **`@Autowired`**, and it does compile when not using it.

UPDATE:

After investigating and following instructions given in comments, I've noticed that the log is showing multiple **`java.lang.NullPointerException`**, after those messages (for another beans):

```
Creating shared instance of singleton bean 'x'
...
Processing injected method of bean 'x': AutowiredFieldElement for private package.ws.y package.ws.y.x
```

Tests are also not compiling whenever there's an `@Autowired` private field (no matter which one and even for **`ApplicationContext`**) in the `ServiceImplTest`.

```
Caught exception while allowing TestExecutionListener [org.springframework.test.context.support.DependencyInjectionTestExecutionListener@1c1fbd9] to prepare test instance [package.ws.services.x.ServiceImplTest@16f2b7f]
java.lang.IllegalStateException: Failed to load ApplicationContext
```

UPDATE2:

I tried what @Louis Steimberg mentioned (without defining the loader) and now I get

```
testFunction(package.ws.services.x.ServiceImplTest): Error creating bean with name 'packge.ws.services.x.ServiceImplTest': Injection of autowired dependencies failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Could not autowire field: private package.ws.services.x.ServiceTest package.ws.services.x.ServiceImplTest.serviceTest; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No matching bean of type [package.ws.services.x.ServiceTest] found for dependency: expected at least 1 bean which qualifies as autowire candidate for this dependency. Dependency annotations: {@org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired(required=true)}
```

It looks like it can't create the bean for some reason.

Comment: you can skip test cases execution using maven command : mvn clean instsall -Dmaven.test.skip=true for successful build.

Comment: Indeed. That's not the point. What we want is to add tests to the project

Comment: What package is your Service class located in?

Comment: @ravi comment of the year :) testing is definitely overrated.

Comment: @Plog I can't give more info because of confidentiality, but just imagine it's `com.myCompany.myProject.myApp.api.services.myService.Service.java` (and its implementation is `com.myCompany.myProject.myApp.ws.services.myService.ServiceImpl.java`)

Comment: How have you created service bean ? Annotation or XML? Can you confirm if you have created it?

Comment: @TmP I guess so. Does not `@Service` annotation serve this purpose? How can I confirm it otherwise? Some debug tip or check? Thanks

Comment: @Service + correct package in <context:component-scan ...> should work.try applicationcontext.getbean() ?

Comment: What I mainly meant @jjimenezg93 is: Is Service under the package "com.x.api" because thats what youre component scanning

Comment: My very wild guess is, it has to do something with your profile. Have you created service with profiles?

Comment: @Plog alright. It is, indeed, under `package.api`

Comment: @TmP I'm trying to get that bean using what you mentioned. In the mean time, neither the Service nor the ServiceImpl have `@Profile`, so I'd say no. I'll check if any .xml added a profile for it

Comment: "It is not working when using @Autowired, and it does compile when not using it." You mean test executes without annotation ?

Answer (score 0):

You should add this param to your @ContextConfiguration annotation :

```
@ContextConfiguration(
    classes = {TestConfig.class },
    loader = AnnotationConfigWebContextLoader.class
    )
```

and in TestConfig.class :

```
@Configuration
@ComponentScan(basePackages = "com.your.component.package1, com.your.component.package2")
public class TestConfig {

// You can put some beans here

}
```

Comment: I can't import `org.springframework.test.context.web.AnnotationConfigWebContextLoader` as I see in [Spring docs](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/test/context/web/AnnotationConfigWebContextLoader.html). It can't resolve `AnnotationConfigWebContextLoader` when importing `org.springframework.test.context`. Thanks

Comment: You might try without loader = AnnotationConfigWebContextLoader.class I guess, maybe using your loader value you showcased in your post, the important thing here is the classes = {TestConfig.class}

Comment: hum, weird, maybe you should keep the initial value of your locations param as well  locations = { "classpath:spring-config-business-test.xml"}) ? Did you also put in your TestConfig class the right packages that contains the bean declaration you try to instanciate? You might want to add your Configuration class (form main directory) as well in the classes param